# Understanding argv and *++argv[0]

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments, argv

From *chapter 5.10 of K&R*'s C book the idea of `argv` has been introduced to allow for command line arguments.

`argv` is a pointer to an array of character pointers. Taking this, how does the following code check that the argument supplied starts with a hyphen?

```
(*++argv)[0] == '-'
```

From my understanding the `[0]` is the same as `*(argv + 0)`, so if I take the value of `( *++argv)` then combine it with `*(argv + 0)` what do I actually get?

I know it returns the first characters of the argument string, but how? From my understanding:

1. `(*++argv)` - The value `argv` points to is retrieved (which gives another pointer)
2. `[0]` or `*(argv + 0)` - Then the next pointer to the next arguments pointer is returned from this statement.
3. I don't see how the first char of the argument is obtained from this statement.

Comment: `argv[0]` is the same as `*(argv + 0)`. But you don't have `argv[0]`. You have `(*++argv)[0]`, so it's `*(*++argv + 0)`.

Comment: @chris how did you 'combine' the (*++argv) and [0] to produce *(*++argv + 0)? Could you go through it in steps so I can understand the derivation?

Comment: `X[Y]` is equivalent to `*(X + Y)`. X is `(*++argv)` and Y is `0`. The parentheses around X are redundant after the transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's separate out the `++` for clarity:

```
argv = argv + 1;
```

Then we have:

```
(*argv)[0] == '-'
```

(I'm presuming this appears in an `if` statement).

Bear in mind that the definition of `p[0]` is `*(p+0)`, i.e. `*p` . So this is the same as `argv[0][0] == '-'` .

`argv[0]` is a `char *` which points to the first character of a string. So `argv[0][0]` is the first character of that string.

The effect of `argv = argv + 1;` is to make `argv` point to the next `char *` which follows directly in memory after the previous one.

`argv` is a thing which points to `char *`  (it is not a `char *` itself). There are some `char *` in adjacent memory, each of which points to a string located somewhere else in memory. Using `argv` you can iterate over that list of `char *`.

Comment: The use of ++argv indicates that it would be used in a while loop; argv gets advanced by each application of the ++ in the loop. Also, having the ++ as a prefix rather than suffix initializes it to the second element, which is the first option (the first element is the program name).